# CSS linear gradient for div with dynamic height

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend, gradient, linear-gradients

I need to create a linear gradient like this [Gradient requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzaXn.png)

I am trying to achieve it with css like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(-60deg,
          rgba(255,183,107,1) 0%,
          rgba(255,167,61,1) 15%,
          rgba(255,124,0,1) 15%,
          rgba(255,127,4,1) 100%);
```

This works for a specific height, but as the height of the div changes the shape of gradient changes as shown here [Issue when height of div increases or decreases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLADA.png).
I want that the gradient should always touch the top right corner of div.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code it like below:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#0000 50%,rgba(255,183,107,1) 50.1%) 
        top right /1000px 1730px no-repeat /* 1.73 = tan(60deg) */
    rgba(255,127,4,1);
    
    /* resize and see the result*/
    resize:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```